# Как (прописная-строчная) пишется папа римский при прямом порядке слов?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В Инете, на форумах, в Справке Грамоты, нешуточные сражения за "прописная-строчная"...

А Вики нам не указ? Как править-то?

> Пасхалий II — Википедия
>
> [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пасхалий_II](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_II)
>
> Святейший Пасха́лий II (лат. Paschalis PP. II), в миру Ранье́ро Бье́да
>   (итал. Raniero Bieda; ? — 21 января 1118) — **Папа Римский** с 13
>   августа 1099 года по 21 января 1118 года.

У меня:

> В XI веке папа римский Пасхалий II (1099–1118) заложил на месте
>   часовни небольшой храм в честь Девы Марии. Во время страшной чумы 1231
>   года папа Григорий IX (1145/47 – 1241) расширил пространство церкви,
>   чтобы разместить в ней чудотворный образ Девы Марии – открыть
>   отчаявшимся людям доступ к иконе «написанной самим Святым Лукой».

*Папа Григорий IX (1145/47 – 1241)* - отбивки вокруг тире я сама нарисовала, правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше оставить авторский вариант "**папа римский, папа Григорий**", прописная буква рекомендована для церковной тематики, хотя встречается и в обычных текстах.

В ноябре 1979 года **Папа Римский Иоанн Павел II** официально признал, что инквизиция в 1633 году совершила ошибку, силой вынудив Галилея отречься ученого от теории Коперника. [Наталия Басовская, Г. Бельская. «И все-таки она вертится...» // «Знание - сила», 2008]

Справедливости ради надо сказать: в 1992 году **папа римский Иоанн Павел II** объявил решение суда инквизиции от 22 июня 1633 года ошибочным. [В. Каганов. Можно ли жить своим умом? Об отринутых и проклятых... // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

Comment: А тире с отбивками имеет объяснение?

Comment: При обозначении (цифрами) интервала используется так называемое техническое тире, которое не требует отбивки пробелами. По рисунку такое тире совпадает с пунктуационным знаком тире. http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=отбивки

Comment: Ррр... У тамочки - (1099–1118) - я и нарисовала без отбивок, а у туточки - (1145/47 – 1241) мне мешают сдвоенные 45/47...